# Exporting raster in ArcGIS changes pixel value and adds a pixel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have a raster that has pixels with values between 0-3 with the following info:

Columns: 2000
Rows: 13000
Values: Min = 1, Maximum = 3.
Unique Values: 1,2,3

When I export my raster by right clicking the layer and using "data export", the exported raster has a change in pixel values.

Exported raster's info:

Columns: 2000
Rows: 13000
Values: Min = 0, Maximum = 255.
Unique Values: 0,1,2,3,255.

Sometimes, there is also an increase in the number of column pixels. e.g.,

Columns: 2001
Rows: 13000
Values: Min = 0, Maximum = 255.
Unique Values: 0,1,2,3,255.

How can I stop my exported raster from changing  from changing its pixel values and changing in the total number of pixels?

Note: the raster is 8 bit unsigned and is exported as such. When exporting rasters of the same dimensions, only some end up with an additional column pixels and other stay the same. Regardless, they all end up with a change in pixel value range through the addition of 0 and 255 value pixels.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the parameters you used in the export raster dialog.

Comment: Use raster calculator instead.

Comment: Export is adding the 255 value to account for nodata in 8-bit data.